# Filtrado con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta sentencia en JQuery para filtrar datos tipo JSON

```
 var datos = $(Data).filter(function (index, value) {

            return value.Apellido == Apellido;
    });
```

Donde Data es mi concentrado de datos, quiero filtrar los que tengan un apellido X, me lo hace de forma correcta, pero sólo si el apellido que doy es estrictamente igual a como está en la tabla, es decir, no es lo mismo "Hernández" a " Hernández ". Hay alguna forma de hacer un tipo LIKE como en SQL?

Comment: No lo hay, tienes que usar expresiones regulares para encontrar patrones como en este caso letras que conforman el apellido

Comment: Lo que pasa es que a veces me mandan datos como "Pérez", "  Pérez", "Pérez   " y pues obviamente si lo comparo con el apellido "Pérez" pues no me lo detecta como lo mismo aunque si lo sea :/

Comment: Entonces tienes que manipular los strings para quitar espacios o cualquier otro caracter que no busques, lo otro es hacer esa manipulación desde la base de datos que uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes complicarlo tanto como quieras.

Por ejemplo:

```
var datos = $(Data).filter(function (index, value) {
  return value.Apellido.toUpperCase().indexOf(Apellido.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
});
```

Vendría a ser lo que un `LIKE '%XXXX%'` en SQL, sin diferenciar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.
Otra opción es la de utilizar expresiones regulares, pero lo primero que tienes que tener claro es qué reglas quieres aplicar a la búsqueda.

Comment: Me sirvió muchisimo, gracias! Nunca había usado eso, que es lo que realiza indexOf??

Comment: Busca una cadena dentro de otra y devuelve la posición en que se encuentra ó -1 si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia. Ver: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf